# CalculatePrice message in Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I have been assigned to maintain customization code developed by consultants. This code includes a custom price calculation plugin that is based on a Microsoft [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/dn817877(v=crm.8)). As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/dn817885%28v%3Dcrm.8%29), the plugin has been registered to fire on the `CalculatePrice` message.

While debugging the code, I noticed that just loading or refreshing a Quote would cause the `CalculatePrice` message to be fired. Further investigation seems to confirm that issuing a `Retrieve` message triggers a `CalculatePrice` message (sort of corroborated on [GitHub](https://github.com/delegateas/XrmMockup/issues/25)).

[image: Quick-Watch of Context Variable]

This behavior makes no sense to me. It results in performance penalties and unnecessarily large transaction logs. Logically, the only time `CalculatePrice` should fire is on `Create` or `Update` messages of relevant records/fields (kind of like workflow activities).

As such, here are some questions:

1. Is anyone aware of *good* documentation on the topic?
2. Is this out-of-the-box behavior or a result of incorrect configuration?
3. If this is out-of-the-box behavior, what is the reason/justification for it?
4. Is there harm in altering code to return if parent context message is `Retrieve`?
5. Has anybody else ran into this? If so, how did you solve it?

Any answer(s) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From sales patch version of 9.0.1904.XXXX Dynamics CRM will not be triggering the PriceCalculation always in retrieve message.